# Matrix multiplication and addition in R

Tags: r, matrix, operators

Perhaps I am not using the right terms in my search, but I was wondering if anyone could point out an easy way of doing the following:

I have two matrices:

```
mat1 = matrix(1:12, 3)
mat2 = matrix(c(1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2), 2, 4)
```

I want to multiply each of row in a certain column of `mat1` by the first row of `mat2`. For example, column 3 of `mat1` would become `(7*3, 8*3, 9*3)=(21, 24, 27)`. After this, I want to add the second row of `mat2` to each row in a certain column of `mat1`, so the column 3 would become `(21+2, 24+2, 27+2) = (23, 26, 29)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the code below

```
t(t(mat1)*mat2[1,]+mat2[2,])
```

such that

```
> t(t(mat1)*mat2[1,]+mat2[2,])
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    6   23   12
[2,]    4    7   26   13
[3,]    5    8   29   14
```